# Shopping cart output repeating first entry

Tags: php, duplicates, cart, recordset

I have set up a shopping cart on a website that I'm building. I can easily add items, remove items and clear the cart. What I'm having a problem with is actually displaying the items in the cart, or more to the point the relevant database entries.

The PHP session variable holds numbers which relate to ID numbers used to identify items in a database. I need the cart to then show an image, a name, a delete option and the id number. When displaying the cart if there is more than one item the image and name are always the first item in the cart repeated for each entry, while the id number does change.

This makes me think that I am only performing one query when in fact I need to run the query inside the foreach loop of my first code segment below. As a bit of a newby to PHP, I'm not too sure the best way to go about this. I've just added a recordset via Dreamweaver (second code).

Could someone point in the best direction for guiding me to solve my little problem.

Many thanks

**Shopping Cart Display:**

```
    <?php 
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
  if (!$cart) {echo "<div class='dialogue_box_inside_info_request'>
 <div class='dialogue_box_image'>
    <img src='images/basket_empty_dialogue.png' width='618' height='264' />
    </div>
</div>";}
  else
  {

      $array = explode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);

  echo "<table width='835' border = '0'>";
  foreach($array as $cartId) {
  $ship_name = $row_ships['ship_name'];
  $ship_image = $row_ships['image'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width='110' height='58' class='table_text'><img src='images/ships/$ship_image'width='83' height='53' /> </td>";
  echo "<td width='620' height='58' class='table_text'>$ship_name</td>";
  echo "<td width='35' height='58' class='table_text'><a href='cart.php?action=delete&ship_id=$cartId'><img src='images/trash.png' width='31' height='42' /></a></td>";
  echo "<td height='58'>$cartId</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table>";

  }
   ?>
```

**Recordset placed at top of code**

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_ships, $ships);
$query_ships = "SELECT ship_id, ship_name, image FROM ship_infomation";
$ships = mysql_query($query_ships, $ships) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ships = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships);
$totalRows_ships = mysql_num_rows($ships);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need to run your query inside your loop; that goes against the nature/intent of SQL databases (put simply - and barring poor DB design - one query = fast, many iterated queries = slow).

The problem seems to be with your foreach loop. Your data array, as fetched in your second code block, is $row_ships, which you use within your foreach loop to assign $ship_name and $ship_image.

However, I don't see you looping through the $row_ships array. Your loop advances through $array (populated outside your loop via the $_SESSION['cart'] string), giving you a different $cartId for each iteration. However, $ship_name = $row_ships['ship_name'] is the same assignment for every iteration (which also goes for $image).

If $cartId corresponds with ship_id in your table, you need to make that connection within your loop, such that the correct ship_name and image are used for each value of $cartId.

Comment: Thank you for your time to make a great response. That's what I had sort of guessed, and I think you'll probably understand my poor logic of moving the query into the loop. Are you able to shed some light on how I should link $cartId and ship_name, I'm not sure how to begin doing that.

Comment: If they need to be linked, there has to be a relation: that is, a way to know which cartId goes with which table row. I can't infer too much as to what that may be, as I don't know your schema, etc. Your session cart variable is a comma separated string of cart ids, yes? Do you add to it when a product is added to the cart? What exactly does that id represent? If it can be matched to a product id in your DB, which can be matched to the ship_id, then it's no problem matching things up. If not, you might consider adding more info into your session data than just the cartId.

Comment: Hi Centuren, you're quite right, the cart is a set of CSV's... each cartId value is numeric. The items are indeed added on each product page. The products all have their own ID (ship_id). The actual number for cartId and ship_id are identical, hence me thinking it was a more simple process that in it is! Do you think it's quite an easy fix? thank you for your time.